# What skill is used to decipher a magic scroll?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, skills

Which skill do I use when deciphering a scroll? Can I choose, or is it said anywhere?

(If I *can* choose, is there any reason to ever choose Use Magic Device, since its DC is higher?)

Comment: I'm just reading the skill descriptions and this struck me as wierd...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Magic Items on [Scrolls](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsSSW.html#_top) on [Decipher the Writing](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsSSW.html#scroll-decipher-the-writing) says

> The writing on a scroll must be deciphered before a character can use it or know exactly what spell it contains. This requires a [*read magic*](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsPtoR.html#read-magic) spell or a successful [Spellcraft](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpapr/dnd35/soveliorsage/skillsAll.html#spellcraft) check (DC 20 + spell level). Deciphering a scroll to determine its contents does not activate its magic unless it is a specially prepared cursed scroll. A character can decipher the writing on a scroll in advance so that he or she can proceed directly to the next step when the time comes to use the scroll.

Alternatively, a creature can decipher the writing on a scroll with a [Use Magic Device](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device) skill check (DC 25 + spell level), and "[t]his usage works just like deciphering a written spell with the Spellcraft skill, except that the DC is 5 points higher. Deciphering a written spell requires 1 minute of concentration."

One reason a creature would opt to employ the skill Use Magic Device instead of the skill Spellcraft to decipher a scroll's writing is if the creature lacks the skill Spellcraft, a skill which can't be used untrained. A rogue, for example, has as a class skill the skill Use Magic Device but not the skill Spellcraft.

Comment: Beyond lacking the skill in class, there's also the possibility of simply having a much higher *Use Magic Device* score (for example because of a high Charisma/low Intelligence).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yep. That's certainly another reason, especially for the typical bard.